# How to convert a 2d numpy array into a 1d numpy array by summing the values and not using for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

Is there a numpy function which can combine a 2d numpy array into a 1d numpy array. I want to do it without using a for loop.

Example:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0], [0 1 0 0 0]] => [1 1 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the ndarray method [sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) along row axis:

```
arr2d = np.array([[1, 3, 8, 2, 0], [0, 1, 0, 5, 1]])

arr1d = arr2d.sum(axis=0)

>>> array([1, 4, 8, 7, 1])
```